# How to include a php file with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to include javascript for my file `index.php` , the problem is the javascript is inside a php file extension `charts.php` and when I try to link the javascript to my index.php it dosent work, so how do I link `charts.php` to `index.php`?

I've tried

```
<script>
    <?php include_once "../assets/js/charts.php";?>
</script>
```

as well as

```
<script src="../assets/js/charts.php"></script>
```

both of which don't work.

sample `charts.php`

```
<!-- Gender stats of user -->
<script type=''>
var options = {
    chart: {
        height: 320,
        type: 'pie',
    }, 
    <?php echo "series: [$gender[0],$gender[1],$gender[2]],"?>
    labels: ['Male','Female','Not specify'],
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        floating: false,
        fontSize: '14px',
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 7
    },
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 600,
        options: {
            chart: {
                height: 240
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
        }
    }]

}

var chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#gender-pie-user"),
    options
);

chart.render();
</script>
```

While `charts.php` has a php file extension, its mostly Javascript with a few php variables from my database. I should note that if I included the `charts.js` code directly inside index.php it works.

for example, this works:

```
// index.php
<script type=''>
var options = {
    chart: {
        height: 320,
        type: 'pie',
    }, 
    <?php echo "series: [$gender[0],$gender[1],$gender[2]],"?>
    labels: ['Male','Female','Not specify'],
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        floating: false,
        fontSize: '14px',
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 7
    },
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 600,
        options: {
            chart: {
                height: 240
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
        }
    }]

}

var chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#gender-pie-user"),
    options
);

chart.render();
</script>
```

While this does not work:

```
// index.php
<script src='../assets/js/charts.php'></script>
```

Comment: Did you check what the browser console had to say, when you tried `<script src='../assets/js/charts.php'></script>` ...? I'm guessing it probably said there that the browser refused to execute this as script code, because the Content-Type header said `text/html` ...

Answer (score 2):

```php
<?php require __DIR__ . "/../assets/js/charts.php";?>
```

Is the one that should be working. Switch it to require to see if the path can be resolved at all. I would also advice to start it with `__DIR__` - make the path absolute.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not output content as default.
So when you do this:

```
<script>
    <?php include_once "../assets/js/charts.php";?>
</script>
```

you actually just includes the content from charts.php into memory, but never outputs it.

Something like this is more likely to work:

```
<script>
    <?php echo require("../assets/js/charts.php");?>
</script>
```

Comment: And as Bjørn Büttner suggested try to prefix the relative path with `__DIR__` to ensure that the path is resolved from the directory of the including file. E.g. `require(__DIR__ . "/../assets/js/charts.php")`

Comment: Look at the contents of charts.php. your idea would put a script block inside a script block, which isn't going to work. and a .PHP file will still auto output anything which isn't within a `<?php` tag (because actually it's the webserver which outputs that non-php content, it never goes to PHP). Not quite sure how this answer managed any upvotes

Comment: @ADyson I took your advice and removed the script tags inside charts.php and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to save your dynamic php data to a html **data-attribute** like this:

```
<?php
$gender_arr =[
    'male',
    'female',
    'not_specify'
];
?>
<div id="gender-pie-user" data-series='<?php echo json_encode($gender_arr);?>'></div>
```

Example output:

```
<div id="gender-pie-user" data-series='["male","female","not_specify"]'></div>
```

This way you could save your chart init script as a static js file:

```js
    let genderPie = document.querySelector("#gender-pie-user");
    
    // render chart if #genderPie element exists
    if(genderPie){
    
        let genderPieSeries = genderPie.getAttribute('data-series');
        var options = {
            chart: {
                height: 320,
                type: 'pie',
            }, 
            //parse data attribute
            series: JSON.parse(genderPieSeries),
            labels: ['Male','Female','Not specify'],
            legend: {
                show: true,
                position: 'bottom',
                horizontalAlign: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                floating: false,
                fontSize: '14px',
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 7
            },
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 600,
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        height: 240
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false
                    },
                }
            }]
        }
    
        var chart = new ApexCharts(
            genderPie,
            options
        );
    
        chart.render();
    }
```

This way you can easily reuse your initializing function for different chart data views and benefit from static js file caching.